# Alignment of text using clistctrl

Tags: listview

first one does not align the text in center, but when i change the column to 1 the second one does . any reasons why

m_dataList.InsertColumn(0, _T("FLOOR"), LVCFMT_CENTER, (rect.Width() )/9);

m_dataList.InsertColumn(1, _T("FLOOR"), LVCFMT_CENTER, (rect.Width() )/9);

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
LVCOLUMN Column;
Column.mask = LVCF_FMT ;
Column.fmt = LVCFMT_RIGHT;
YourCListCtrl.SetColumn( 0, &Column );
```